# call gui generated using lwuit gui builder from main class

Tags: java-me, lwuit

hello i just create gui called for example LoginForm using lwuit resource editor gui builder (application>advance>generate ui state machine).

how to call this LoginForm from my main class?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use it that way. You should use "Generate NetBeans project" and work with that.